# Linux kernel mode string copy

Tags: c, linux-kernel

After few minutes of search for string copy on kernel mode, thought of posting a new question.

What utility will help me to do a string copy when the code runs in **Kernel Mode** ?

I'm sure there should be something there and in my current project I see code that uses `memcpy()` that does the function of `strcpy()`.

Yes, I agree that it's just a single line code for `strcpy()`, but you know that those may not be accepted in code reviews  :)

EDIT : I'll put my question in a better way,
Does `strcpy()` be used in kernel mode ? (say linux kernel 2.6 and after)  If so, is it using the libc or some other util ?

PS:
I see `strcpy()` http://livegrep.com/search/linux?q=strcpy is used in kernel source code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for as an answer... But the linux kernel provides [strcpy()](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/linux/string.h?h=v3.8.6#n20) and [memcpy()](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/linux/string.h?h=v3.8.6#n99).

If you're asking about how `strcpy()` and friends are recommended against in code reviews, you could use `strncpy()`. Most of the traditional C string functions are defined, and most are defined in `include/linux/string.h`

Comment: Thanks Sharth.  I've just edited my question, assuming that no one would read it so quick :)

Comment: As to your new question, the linux kernel does NOT include libc, glibc, or any other external implementation of libc. It implements it itself, in various architecture specific directories.

Comment: As you say, [lxr](http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#uboot+v2012.04/arch/blackfin/lib/string.c) gives the detail. I got the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the Linux source tree, various utility functions are in the *lib* sub-directory. There is the *[string.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/lib/string.c)* file where functions like *strcpy()*, *strcasecmp()* and so on are provided.

But if you want a robust code which passes code reviews, you should use the robust versions of some services when it is possible. The [Documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/process/deprecated.rst) in the source code tree specifies the functions which are not safe and the proposed replacements:

> . Use strscpy() instead of strcpy(), strncpy() and strlcpy()
> . Use kstrtol(), kstrtoll(), kstrtoul(), kstrtoull() respectively instead of simple_strtol(), simple_strtoll(), simple_strtoul() and simple_strtoull()